# Pass certificate to TNetHTTPClient

Tags: delphi, soap, client-certificates

I'm using component of class `TNetHTTPClient` in order to make SOAP call. I need to set certificates that will be used for communication.

I know I can set certificate from certificate storage on event:

```
procedure TForm1.NetHTTPClientNeedClientCertificate  (const Sender: TObject; const ARequest: TURLRequest;  const ACertificateList: TCertificateList; var AnIndex: integer);
var
  i: integer;
begin

  for i := 0 to ACertificateList.Count do
  begin
    ...
    ACertificateList.Items[i - 1];
    ...
  end;

  AnIndex := 1; //selected certificate index

end;
```

But I would like to use certificate not from storage, but from file. I have PFX file that contains certificate data. How to pass it for `NetHTTPClient` ?

Comment: This question seems to be unrelated to SOAP

Comment: Can you just install the PFX certificate in order to get it to show up in the CertificateList?